# How can I inject a stateless session bean into a servlet?

Tags: java, jpa, servlets

My high-level goal is to use the JPA code generated by NetBeans by using the create "RESTful web services from a database" wizard in my servlets.

To be more precise, I would like to access the facade directly from a servlet to avoid having to load some of the data using JavaScript on the client side.

The relevant part of my facade looks like this:

```
@Stateless
@Path("wgm.rest.balanceview")
public class BalanceViewFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<BalanceView> {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "WGManagerPU")
  private EntityManager em;

  @GET
  @Override
  @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
  public List<BalanceView> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
  }

}
```

Now what I tried is the following:

```
@WebServlet(name = "BalanceServlet", urlPatterns = "/balance/*")
public class BalanceServlet extends HttpServlet {

   @Inject
   private BalanceViewFacadeREST balanceFacade;


  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws
  ServletException, IOException {
    List<BalanceView> balances = balanceFacade.findAll();
    // ...
  }
}
```

However, when deploying to GlassFish, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load the EJB module. DeploymentContext does not contain any EJB. Check the archive to ensure correct packaging for /home/severin/Projects/WGManager/build/web.
If you use EJB component annotations to define the EJB, and an ejb or web deployment descriptor is also used, please make sure that the deployment descriptor references a Java EE 5 or higher version schema, and that the metadata-complete attribute is not set to true, so the component annotations can be processed as expected
```

This sounds to me as if the injector could not find BalanceViewFacadeREST. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that you Servlet and your EJB are local to each other. My presumption is based that your EJB does not have a remote interface.

If the Servlet and the EJB reside in the same container you can just anotate with @EJB or @Inject if you have Context and Dependncy injection in the container  is also an option.

Since you are neither presenting a REMOTE neither LOCAL interface your EJB is of No-Interface type. This mean you  should annotate the EJB with **@LocalBean**

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Path("wgm.rest.balanceview")
public class BalanceViewFacadeREST



 //@Inject
    OR
 // @EJB
  private BalanceViewFacadeREST balanceFacade;
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I am really new to EJB so I don't really know why we need @LocalBean but I guess I will have to dive deeper into this topic.
Anyway, this resolved the above issue, but now I get a severe log message:
"Severe:   Class [ Lwgm/rest/service/BalanceViewFacadeREST; ] not found. Error while loading [ class wgm.servlets.BalanceServlet ]" and I get 404 for all my paths (also the ones unrelated to /balance). Could that be related or is this another problem? Btw, im using Glassfish version 4.1.1.

Comment: I no longer get the severe log message, since I completely cleaned and rebuilt the application and deleted the 'generated' and 'osgi-chache' directories in Glassfish (just to be sure). It seems to be a problem with NetBeans deploying to Glassfish. When I manually copy the war-archive to the Glassfish autodeploy folder, it works fine. But I think I will open a new question for that issue.